# Computing Bezier Arc length 3D C++

Tags: c++, bezier, geometric-arc

Im having 4 vector3's holding positions of 4 points for a cubic bezier curve in 3D space. I want to compute arc length, Any help would be appreciated. Thanks .

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski google yields a ton of potential solutions. I think you should explicitly elaborate on what's wrong with these potential solutions; I'd post a new question if I were you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend, showing an article on gamedev.net: [Calculating the length of a Bezier curve...](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/313018-calculating-the-length-of-a-bezier-curve/)